# Getting workgroup and domain computers with net view

Tags: powershell

Ok, here's the situation. I have a group of windows 7 computers, about 3-8. Most of them have been connected to a bigger network before, and therefore they all have the same domain, called `win`. Some of them haven't been connected to this bigger network, and do not have a domain.

I will be connecting this group of computers into smaller networks. I'll take a subset of them and connect to each other. I'll be done multiple times and not with the same subset all the time.

When I do this, I want to be able to know which of the computers are connected, and if they have any shared drives. I'm using powershell for this, and in the powershell script I'm using `net view`.

Now to the problem. From a domain computer, I'm able to get all the other domain computers with `net view`. But I can't get the computers that isn't in the domain. From a non-domain computer I can get the domain computers with `net view /domain:win`. But I can't get all computers in a reliable way.

So I'm thinking, either I remove the domain from all computers, and create a homegroup. None of them will ever be connected to the bigger network with the domain server again (for security reasons), so this probably makes the most sense. I'm guessing I can't add the non-domain computers to the `win` domain without connecting it to the domain server?

But the solution I'd like the most would be if I could get all computers, both domain and non-domain with `net view`, or some other command.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For your domain connected machines, i would reccommend using `Get-ADComputer` such as

```
$days = (Get-Date).Adddays(-7)
Get-ADComputer -Properties lastlogondate -Filter {lastlogondate -gt $days} | select name,lastlogondate
```

This is listing all computers who have logged on in the past 7 days on your domain. Where (-7) is how many days you deem to be an 'active' machine. 
Depending on the size of your AD, you may want to lock this query down to a particular Organisation Unit to avoid returning Servers etc.

Not 100% on your non domain machines, do you already have their DNS names or do you need to find them as part of this exercise?

Comment: Once the domain-computers are off the bigger network, and put into my litte group, they will never be logged on to the domain again. After that they are used with `computername\user`-login. So I guess I'll have to set the `lastlogondate` to infinity... I don't have the DNS names of the non-domain computers. Or well I do, but I'd like to not have to put a list of all of them in the script. The list would need to change often then.

Comment: Well if you just need to list "all" computers, you can change the filter to `enabled -eq $true` just to ensure the computer accounts are still active, no reason to use lastlogondate in your case. In my experience most domains are full of old computer accounts.

Comment: Is it possible to use Get-ADComputer at all with windows 7? I've only seen some references to win8 and server2012, can't find anything related to win7. It isn't available by default

Comment: Certainly is available! It has nothing to do with the clients, it's an Active Directory cmdlet that queries AD for Computer Accounts. If powershell doesnt recognise it, it'll be because your missing the AD tools/snap in.
   `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`  If you're running it from a workstation, you'll need the RSAT Tools installed first: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7887

Comment: Yep tried that, still won't work. Even if it did, installing that ~240mb update on all computers will be more of an effort than removing the domain on them. So I'll have to look into other options. Thanks for your effort anyway!

Comment: Not a problem, perhaps take a look at psexec? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx